# AngularJS ng-CKeditor inline doesn't show table tools buttons

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

Does anyone have a solution? I've tried to download the full preset from CKeditor website, but just a subset of buttons is showed in inline editor.

Here's my config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ){

config.toolbar = 'Custom';

config.toolbar_Custom =
[
    { name: 'document', items : [ 'NewPage','Preview' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','Scayt' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak'
             ,'Iframe' ] },
            '/',
    { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Strike','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote' ] },
    { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize','-','About' ] }
];};
```

Answer (score -1):

that's not how you do it.

You need to pass the config settings into the directive scope. This is pretty plainly explained on the [github page](https://github.com/esvit/ng-ckeditor)

**HTML**

```
<textarea ckeditor="editorOptions"></textarea>
```

**angular**

```
$scope.editorOptions = {
    toolbarButtons: [
        { name: 'document', items : [ 'NewPage','Preview' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','Scayt' ] },
        { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak','Iframe' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format' ] },
        { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Strike','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote' ] },
        { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
        { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize','-','About' ] }
    ]
};
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Plus it's not indicated this way in the documentation you linked at all.

Comment: edited first post, because you're right, that didn't work. Seems like i answered too quickly. Either way, it is indicated on the github page... just vaguely and indirectly. `editorOptions` is the equivalent of `CKEDITOR.editorConfig`. Whatever key you would set on config in the callback, you would add to the editorOptions object.